# Does Windows std::thread uses internally PPL?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ppl

Is the implementation of Visual Studio 2015's std::thread internally based on PPL's task system?

The background of my question is, does it make sense to use std::thread for several tasks, because they are already executed balanced on the common threadpool, or is it better to execute the tasks via PPL tasks?

According to ([Which std::async implementations use thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666443/which-stdasync-implementations-use-thread-pools)) this seems to be, but since the question is rather old I would like to get an "official" answer.

Comment: It uses the same foundation as PPL, the concurrency runtime.  It is an (almost) complete replacement of the OS primitives, focus was on getting better scaling on many-core CPUs.  And I suspect the somewhat idle hope that it will be ported some day.  It is not a great joy to debug btw.  std::thread is a rather bare class, use PPL for what it adds.  Like a threadpool, parallel_for, etcetera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and No.

for `std::thread`:
`std::thread` constructor (`thread` file) calls
`_Launch` (`xthread` file) which calls
 `_Thrd_startX` (`xthread` file) which calls
 `_Thrd_start`(`cthread.c` file)  which calls
 `_beginthreadex` (`cthread.c` file).

I don't have `_beginthreadex` code, but in the file `atlbase.h`, some microsoft developer left the following comment :

> ```
> // _beginthreadex calls CreateThread which will set the last error
> // value before it returns.
> ```

so no PPL involed.

But, `std::async` calls `concurrency::create_task` behind the scens, and then it will use the windows API based thread pool.

> The background of my question is, does it make sense to use `std::thread` for several tasks...?

I have used Casablanca which uses PPL. I also played with PPL as standalone. 
 I don't like it at all performance wise. my own threadpool + `std::future` + `std::promise` were literally houndered times faster than `concurrency::task` objects. It is really falls short against the C# version `TPL`. I would only use it if performace does not matter for that project.

Answer (score 6):

[From the horse's mouth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/) :

> We’ve reimplemented the STL’s multithreading primitives to avoid using
>   the Concurrency Runtime (ConcRT).  Using ConcRT was a good idea at the
>   time (2012), but it proved to be more trouble than it was worth.  Now
>   we’re using the Windows API directly

IIRC, PPL was also based on ConcRT, but that doesn't mean that the Standard Library was built on top of PPL. They existed side by side. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32252143/15416) for a stacktrace that captures ConcRT underneath `std::thread`. No PPL in sight.