# Is it safe to call std::thread::join function under Win32 DLL_PROCESS_DETACH?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll, win32-process

Please look at code snippet below // these code blocks defined under **single .cpp unit** in **DLL project**

```
static std::thread sendMessageThread; // define as local static to cpp
bool  callFunction()
{
   /// Some simple code without spawning any thread or fibers
 }
void WINAPI OnEngineStart()
{
    sendMessageThread = std::thread(callFunction);
};

    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
    {
        switch (fdwReason)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            if (sendMessageThread.joinable())
            {
                sendMessageThread.join(); // is this safe?
            }
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
        }

    return TRUE;
};
```

If the process which loaded the DLL call **OnEngineStart** function then whenever it unloads  the DLL(using **FreeLibrary** WinAPI function),
 will it wait until **sendMessageThread**  gets finished? and continue with DLL unload procedure?

Comment: yes. this is deadlock:1. you wait on thread terminated and only after this release loader
    lock
 2. thread wait when you release loader lock and only after this
    terminated
 3. deadlock

Comment: and you need not wait for thread in dll but increment reference count for this dll, before thread start. say via `GetModuleHandleEx`. and on exit thread by call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`

Comment: @RbMm you told "yes" meant -> it is safe? since the std::thread doesn't invoke within DLLMain.. unless it will be deadlock? or still std::thread::join() affect DLL_THREAD_DETACH  and then DLL_PROCESS_DETACH?

Comment: i say that this will be deadlock. and explain why. *yes* was related to previous comment, already deleted

Comment: `std::thread::join() ` wait inside critical section until thread exit. but thread before exit try enter to this critical section for send `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. if you create thread with entry point in dll - you must call `GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, &__ImageBase, )` before create thread. and exit thread by call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` - in this case you need not wait in `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

Comment: [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn’t it?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)

Comment: @RbMm my program didn't crash or halt

Comment: @IInspectable here std::thread wasn't create in DLLMain

Comment: Why does that make a difference? The article I linked to explains what happens, when you try to wait for the thread to terminate in your `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` handler. This is a guaranteed deadlock.

Comment: @IInspectable so when/where can I invoke <code> std::thread::join() 
 </code> function? Should I set semaphore or event under DLL_THREAD_DETACH and upon that signal stop the running thread ? ... If thread stopped before the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH  invoke join function safe right?

Comment: *my program didn't crash or halt* about crash nobody say. if it not deadlock when wait in loader lock for thread exit - this mean that this tread already exited. in this case of course no deadlock.

Comment: @RbMm, [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914735/886887) on older versions of Visual Studio the `std::thread` class uses the concurrency runtime.  It seems to me that this *might* mean that when a C++ thread exits, the corresponding Windows thread is returned to a pool rather than exiting immediately.  **If** my guess is correct, then in older versions of Visual Studio  calling `.join()` doesn't wait for the Windows thread and therefore won't necessarily deadlock.  It *is* just a guess though.

Comment: ... of course, even if that's true, the answer is still the same: no, the code in question isn't safe, because (a) it depends on an implementation detail that has already changed, and (b) you might still run into trouble if the executable isn't sharing the same runtime as the DLL.